# i have 4 variable data,how to display them on jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, netbeans-7

Friends, I have 4 variables with data each time the button is clicked, and I want to add these 4 variables to a JTable named as Bill_Table with 4 Columns.

A new row should be added in the JTable each time the button is clicked.  I tried the following code.  I can read from database and I can have 4 variables, but i can't insert them as a new row in JTable.

How can I achieve this?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         

    item_name=name.getText();
    int item_no=Integer.parseInt(no.getText());
    String sql="SELECT id,price FROM item WHERE item.name='"+item_name+"'";
    try{       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshop","root","mysql");
        java.sql.Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        if (stmt.execute(sql)) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "succes","executed query",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            System.err.println("select failed");}
        int idIndex   = rs.findColumn("id");
        int priceIndex    = rs.findColumn("price");

        while(rs.next()){
            item_id=rs.getInt(idIndex);
            item_price=rs.getInt(priceIndex);

        }
        item_amount = (item_price*item_no);

        Vector  data_rows = new Vector();

        data_rows.addElement(item_name);
        data_rows.addElement(item_price);
        data_rows.addElement(item_no);
        data_rows.addElement(item_amount);

        dtm.addRow(data_rows);
        //dtm is DefaultTableModel object,delared globelly
        bill_table.setModel(dtm);
        //bill_table is table name
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Is there an error?  How does it not complete your objective?

Comment: Why are you NOT using a `PreparedStatement` as was suggested in your last posting?

Comment: camickr, i can read data from database without prepared statement,but the problem is i don't know how to display item_price,item_name,item_no,item_amount at a row in JTable

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way and it's works fine

```
 DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) bill_table.getModel();
 tm.addRow(new Object[]{item_name,item_price,item_no,item_amount});
```